# How to use a Jupyter Notebook with Colcon?

Tags: ros, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a problem that I suspect is easy, but I absolutely can't figure out---any advice is much appreciated.

Here's the situation: I have a standard ROS2/Colcon Python package (ie. basically fresh out of `ros2 pkg create`, built with `ament_python`). This package contains various Python files used in production.

In addition, for prototyping purposes, I'd like to add a Jupyter notebook. I need the notebook to be able to import other files in the package and its dependencies. I don't care if the notebook is included in the build output or not. I don't mind running a build once (or if dependencies change), but I'd really like to avoid re-building every time I change the notebook or an imported file.

I've tried various approaches involving modifications to `sys.path` inside the notebook, but I haven't been able to get anything to work. I think the `--symlink-install` flag to `colcon build` might also be helpful, but I'm not sure exactly how.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417834/how-to-use-a-jupyter-notebook-with-colcon?/) by [ari-reframe](https://answers.ros.org/users/166529/ari-reframe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2023-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, turns out the problem was indeed easy. I was running my Jupyter Notebook from VS Code's built-in editor, which by default spawns its own Jupyter server.

However, sourcing the colcon workspace overlay sets `$PYTHONPATH` such that Python can properly find colcon's packages. Starting the server from VS Code doesn't inherit that env var.

It turns out the answer is simple: just start the notebook server from the terminal and have VS Code connect to it. Problem solved!

---

Originally posted by [ari-reframe](https://answers.ros.org/users/166529/ari-reframe/) with karma: 21 on 2023-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1